# Spring data JPA apply `OrderBy` on Map

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a meeting entity which have association stored into a Map representing equipment quantity.

```
Meeting{
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "equipment_type")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @OrderBy
    @JsonSerialize(using = EquipmentMapSerializer.class)
    private Map<EquipmentType, Integer> equipment = new HashMap<>();
}
```

When I try to serialize meeting entity, the order of entry sets in the equipment map are not fixed, I'd like to know if `@OrderBy` can be applied on Map to sort with map key. If so, what should I add to allow sorting with key.
Thanks.

Comment: @orderby is related to jpa and on how map is stored onto db. Serialization instead regards the "serialization" of the map java object, which, by design, doesn't keep the keys ordered.
By the way you could try to use a TreeMap which should serialize the entries sorted by keys

Comment: @gtosto In the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html), it says `Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued association or element collection **at the point when the association or collection is retrieved**.`

Comment: `@OrderBy` is only a query mechanism

Comment: what about using a List of Embeddables with 2 fields: EquipmentType and Integer instead of a Map. this way you could use @OrderBy and sort by the Integer field. if you still need a map getter you could create a LinkedHashMap starting from the List of embeddables

Answer (score 0):

@OrderBy only sorts the elements in the collection:

From the JPA Spec:

> The OrderBy annotation specifies the ordering the elements of a
>   collection-valued association or element collection are to have when
>   the association or collection is retrieved.

JPA does not sort maps based on the key.

Comment: Is there any alternate solution ? I do see a column that is ordered by , say, EquipmentType_ID (along with Meeting_ID and Map value table. findByIdOrderByEquipmentTypeID is not working.